# binary division in c require assistance

Tags: c

i need help i cant seemed to get the result. the assignment i am doing right now has to do with binary division. the purpose of this project is to try to mimic the ALU and we are not allowed to use the addition or subtraction operator. is there some parts in the code that i am missing?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int subtraction(int operand_1, int operand_2);
int division(int dividen, int divisor);
int addition(int operand_1, int operand_2);
int main()
{
    int operand_1, operand_2,res;
    printf (" enter the value for operand_1(dividen) and operand_2(divisor): ");
    scanf ("%d %d",&operand_1,&operand_2);
    res = division(operand_1,operand_2);
    printf(" binary division: %d\n\n",res);
    
}

int addition(int operand_1, int operand_2)
{
    int carry = operand_2;
    int sum = operand_1;
    while (carry !=0)
    {
        int temp =(sum & carry )<<1;
        sum = sum ^ carry;
        carry = temp;
    }
    return sum; 
}
int subtraction(int operand_1, int operand_2)
{
    operand_2= addition(~operand_2,1);
    return addition (operand_1,operand_2);
}

int division ( int dividen, int divisor)
{
    int i;
    int quotient =0;
    for (i= 0; i < 33 ; i++)
    {
        int remainder =  subtraction(remainder,divisor);

        if (remainder<0)
        {
            remainder = addition(divisor, remainder);
            quotient= quotient << 1 & 0xfe;
        }
        else
        {
            quotient = quotient >> 1 & 0xfe;

        }
        divisor =divisor >> 1 ;
    }
    return quotient;

}
```

Comment: how about the division? is this the correct way to do it?

Comment: i'm checking, i'll tell you

Comment: substraction is working ok, i told you that it was wrong but it works fine.

Comment: @hamboy75 i see thanks mate. is it maybe because i messed up with the division function?

Comment: i dont get why are you iterating 33 times..., it would be 32 if bit based, but if you are substracting it can be more (for example 100000 / 5 would iterate 20k times. Another thing, dividen paramter is not being used in division function

Comment: Binary division is explained here https://byjus.com/maths/binary-division/

Answer (score 1):

#### Issues with the `division()` function presented

Function `division()` initializes its `quotient` variable to 0. It later performs shift operations on it (`quotient >> 1`, `quotient << 1`), and bitwise `&` operations on the shifted results, but all of these will always produce 0 when `quotient` is 0. Those results are the only thing ever assigned back to `quotient`, so the function presented will never return anything other than 0 (unless as a result of exercising undefined behavior).

Moreover, this line is certainly wrong:

> ```
>     int remainder =  subtraction(remainder,divisor);
> ```

It passes the indeterminate initial value of `remainder` to the `subtraction()` function, and uses the undefined result of that as the value of `remainder`.

And perhaps most telling, the function never uses its `dividen` parameter.

If your compiler is not producing warnings about the last two, then you would be well advised to learn how to turn up its warning output, or else to find a more helpful compiler.  On the other hand, if you are ignoring your compiler's warnings then stop doing that.  Compiler warnings are there to help you.  Take the time to understand what they are telling you, and fix the problems they describe, or else be ***sure*** you can explain why it is safe to ignore them.

#### Binary long division

Based on the small, fixed bounds of the `for` loop in the presented `division()` function and its use of bit shifting, I'm inclined to think that you are specifically trying to implement [binary long division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_number#Division).  That would be a reasonable way to go, but the details aren't right at all.

> is there some parts in the code that i am missing?

It's not a matter of some essential detail having been skipped.  Although the algorithm implemented is *reminiscent of* binary long division, there's pretty much nothing correct about it.

Setting aside the questions of negative inputs and division by zero, binary long division could take this general form:

1. Convert dividend and divisor to type `unsigned int`.  This gives you an extra value bit to work with, and it gives you defined behavior in relevant cases where [`signed`] `int` does not.  (See also below.)
2. Shift the (unsigned) divisor left until it exceeds the (unsigned) dividend, then shift it one bit back right.  Let `b` designate the total number of left shifts performed in that process, which may be zero.
3. Initialize the working quotient to 0, and the working remainder to the dividend.
4. Perform the following steps `b` times:

   - shift the working quotient one bit left
   - subtract the (shifted) divisor from the working remainder
   - if the difference is non-negative then

     - set the working remainder to the difference
     - turn on the least-significant bit of the working quotient (equivalently, add 1 to the quotient)
   - (else the difference is negative.  The working remainder should not be updated, and the corresponding quotient bit is (already) zero).
   - shift the divisor one bit right.

After the iterations are finished, the working quotient is the correct binary quotient (of the unsigned operands), and the working remainder is the remainder, as would be computed by the `%` operator.

Note that although the bit-shifting disguises it somewhat, this is the same long division algorithm you learned in grade school, simplified by the fact that 1 and 0 are the only digits to be concerned with.

**If your function must handle negative inputs** then the initial conversion to unsigned must capture information about their signs and yield their absolute values.  The sign information will inform whether the quotient needs to be inverted at the end.

---

I have intentionally avoided writing actual C code for the division function, so as not to rob you of the instructional value of writing that code yourself.  I would encourage you, moreover, to study the algorithm description until you understand what it's doing and why, and then attempt to rewrite your `division()` function without referring further to this answer.

Answer (score 0):

This works. I check for operators sign, if both are - result will be +.

Btw, your keyboard input doesnt work fine for 2 negative values, probably it is better in 2 different lines, in 2 scanfs.

```
int division ( int dividen, int divisor)
{
    char sign=0;
    int i;
    int quotient =0;
    int remainder=dividen;
    if(dividen<0)
    {
        dividen=addition(~dividen,1);
        sign^=1;
    }
    if(divisor<0)
    {
        divisor=addition(~divisor,1);
        sign^=1;
    }
    do
    {
        printf("%d %d\r\n ",quotient ,remainder);

        if (remainder>=divisor)
        {
            quotient= addition(quotient,1);
            remainder=subtraction(remainder,divisor);
        }
    }while(remainder>=divisor);
    if(sign)
      quotient=addition(~quotient,1);
    return quotient;

}
```

Comment: This computes the division result by pure repeated subtraction.  That will produce the right result, but it will be very expensive for some inputs, and it is not an implementation of what I would ordinarily think of as "binary division".

Comment: I agree but it is what he was trying

Comment: No, I don't think it is, but I can see why you might think so.  The bounds on the OP's loop and the bit shifting suggest that they are attempting binary long division.